# $C^{1,\alpha}$ Riemannian metric

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold. What is the definition of a $C^{1,\alpha}$ ($0<\alpha<1$) Riemannian metric on $M$?

Comment: Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hölder_condition) out. Being not sure about the context, I do not put it as an answer.

Comment: I figured it out. Since $Sym^2(T^*M)$ is a parallel subbundle of $T^*M\otimes T^*M$, it inherits a metric $h$ from $T^*M\otimes T^*M$, which is the canonical metric $g$ inherited by the Riemannian metric on $M$. So a $C^{1,\alpha}$ metric $g$ on $M$ is a $C^1$ map from $M$ to $Sym^2(T^*M)$ with the covariant derivative $\nabla_i g$ is Holder continuous with exponent $\alpha$ and is positive definite at every $p\in M$

Comment: Good, so it was Hölder condition.

Comment: The key point here is that one must find a canonical metric on $Sym^2(T^*M)$.